# Android Library AAR depending on another library

Tags: java, android, library-project, aar

Hi I have a Android Library Project which produces an AAR.

All is good but when I use the AAR in another project I get this error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.squareup.picasso.Picasso
```

The AAR makes use of picasso, is it possible to export the dependencies of the AAR as well when generating one?

Comment: How are you using the AAR in the other project?

Comment: Like this:
`repositories {
        flatDir {
            dirs 'libs'   }
        mavenCentral()
    }`
and then including them using the usual groupId format

Comment: This is supposed to be the expected behavior I suppose: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/adt-dev/0ZAP8AVUZVw ! I think i must download the picasso jar and then gradle will include it automatically, otherwise it doesnt. Will give it a try and post an answer

Comment: I have never used `flatDir`. I publish my AARs to a local Maven repo, and it resolves dependencies from there, with no issue.

Comment: using jars instead of maven dependencies works. I guess the idea is you can't mix the two `flatDir` and pure remote dependencies. How can one go about setting up a local maven repo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How can one go about setting up a local maven repo.

WARNING: the following recipe works, but probably could use improvement, as I am *far* from a Maven expert. I hammered out this approach last year for use with my CWAC libraries.

Step #1: Add `classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-plugin:1.0'` to your `buildscript` `dependencies` block in your library project's `build.gradle` file. Also add `version` and `group` statements to provide that information about your AAR.

Step #2: Use **`gradle install`** to compile the AAR and install it in the default local Maven repository.

Step #3: Ordinarily, you would add `mavenLocal()` to the `dependencies` block of your application project to pick up the AAR via its artifact ID. That may be working again, though it was broken for a bit. Instead, use `maven { url "${System.env.HOME}/.m2/repository" }` as a short-term workaround.

So, for example, your library project `build.gradle` file might contain:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.9.+'
        classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-plugin:1.0'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android-library'
apply plugin: 'android-maven'

version '0.4.0'
group 'some.likely.group.name.goes.here'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.2.0'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
}

android {
  // as normal
}
```

You would use **`gradle install`** to publish the JAR to your local Maven repo. Your application project would then have the following stuff in its `build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.9.+'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "${System.env.HOME}/.m2/repository" } // mavenLocal()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'some.likely.group.name.goes.here:name-of-library:0.4.0'
}

android {
    // as normal
}
```

where you replace:

- `some.likely.group.name.goes.here` with something
- `0.4.0` with a version number in X.Y.Z format
- `name-of-library` will be the directory name that contains the Android library project (e.g., `presentation` or `foo`)

Comment: One important thing to note for anyone still using this method like I am: this has since been updated for newer gradle versions. Please refer to the new GitHub here: https://github.com/dcendents/android-maven-gradle-plugin and make sure gradle is at least 2.4 by changing `gradle-wrapper.properties` using instructions here: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/migrating-to-1-0-0

Comment: Please how to use `gradle install` ? I installed gradle for java on windows and tried `gradle install`, I got this error `Task 'install' not found in root project 'bin'.`

Comment: @WilliamKinaan: This answer is 2.5 years old. I recommend finding a newer solution.

Comment: @CommonsWare It makes sense, but I've been reading about Gradle and I just want to know, *just for personal use* how to apply gradle install

Comment: @WilliamKinaan: Either you are missing the cited plugin, or the plugin changed in the past 2.5 years. I am no longer using that plugin, as the standard `maven` plugin and its `uploadArchives` task works fine with modern versions of Android Studio/Android Plugin for Gradle.