# Android Studio cannot find AAR packages

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-library, aar

I am having a problem with Android Studio recognizing classes inside an @aar library imported locally.

So... I've made a library and exported is an aar file. Inside android studio I selected `Import Module` and them `Import .JAR or .AAR Package`.

The project compiles and works with the classes inside the aar file but Android studio can not find the classes or offer any auto completion of so all.

Here is a few of screenshots:

[image: screenshot1]
[image]
[image]

The same problem also happens with other @aar libraries imported the same way:
[image]

Any suggestions?

Edit:

build.gradle:

```
...
dependencies {
   compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
   compile project(':UpPlatformSdk')
   compile project(':simpleorm')
   ... // more libraries here
}
```

settings.gradle:

```
include ':app', ':UpPlatformSdk', ':wear', ':simpleorm'
```

Comment: post your build.gradle

Comment: Posted it. The app can build and execute just fine. The main problem is Android Studio not being able to offer any suggestion or auto completion of so all making it very painful to work with.

Comment: Where do you put your jars? In libs folder?

Comment: Yes. The jar libraries are inside libs and they work just fine. The aar libraries were added through android studio wizard of adding aar libraries

Comment: This seems to be a hiccup between Android Studio and the Gradle for Android 1.1.0 plugin: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/adt-dev/1Ho_c8dALQQ

Comment: Oh dang! Thank you! I will rollback to the 1.0.1 plugin until they fix it them.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you could do this [How to manually include external aar package using new Gradle Android Build System](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16682847/how-to-manually-include-external-aar-package-using-new-gradle-android-build-syst)

If you have them in your lib folder

```
repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile(name:'UpPlatformSdk', ext:'aar')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the quickest way, but this works for autocompletion and also solved my problem of missing classes when I tried compiling my local AAR using the method @puj described. Essentially you need to create a local Maven repository to host the AAR, but any changes you make are pulled by the build system when you do a Gradle sync.

[Android Library AAR depending on another library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23042803/android-library-aar-depending-on-another-library/23045791)